# Choosing the best subset of features

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I want to choose the best feature subset available that distinguish two classes to be fed into a statistical framework that I have built, where features are not independent.

After looking at the feature selection methods on machine learning it seems that it fall into three different categories: Filter,wrapper and Embedded methods. and the filter methods can be either: univariate or multivariate. It does make sense to use either Filter(multivariate) or wrapper methods because both -as I understood- looks for the best subset, however, as I am not using a classifier how can use it ?

1. Does it make sense to apply such methods (e.g. Recursive feature
   elimination ) to DT or Random Forest classifier where the features
   have rules there, and then take the resulted best subset and fed it
   into my framework ?**
2. Also, as most of the algorithms provided by Scikit-learn are
   univariate algorithms, Is there any other python-based libraries
   that provide more subset feature selection algorithms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the statement that "most of the algorithms provided by Scikit-learn are univariate algorithms" is false. Scikit-learn handles multi-dimensional data very nicely. The RandomForestClassifier that they provide will give you an estimate of feature importance.

Another way to estimate feature importance is to choose any classifier that you like, train it and estimate performance on a validation set. Record the accuracy and this will be your baseline. Then take that same train/validation split and randomly permute all values along one feature dimension. Then train and validate again. Record the difference of this accuracy from your baseline. Repeat this for all feature dimensions. The results will be a list of numbers for each feature dimension that indicates its importance.

You can extend this to use pairs, or triples of feature dimensions, but the computational cost will grow quickly. If you're features are highly correlated you may benefit from doing this for at least the pairwise case.

Here is the source document of where I learned that trick: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#varimp
(It should work for classifiers other than Random Forests.)

Comment: Many thanks, this is really useful ... so does this mean I can indeed use a classifier to determine the important features in the feature selection step and then use this important feature to be fed to another framework (not the same classifier which is used in the feature selection step) ?

Comment: I don't see why not. Classifiers are all about teasing how X data can be used to tease out the desired output signal in the y data. They all need to find what information is actually informative (vs noise) at some level. It may be the case that classifiers may disagree about what is important in a signal, but as a feature selection step it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks alot ! That was really helpful